# Our "what topics can I ask about here" help page has been updated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

Based on [this](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/please-give-us-your-feedback-on-the-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-help-pag) Meta discussion, our [what topics can I ask about here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the Help Center has been updated. The following details the changes that were made from the [previous version](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/revisions/49171/14) with the goal of being more *welcoming*, adding *clarity*, and possibly *increasing activity* on our site:

---

1. This first paragraph could have resulted in uncertainty, was a little redundant, and was possibly limiting:

> Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   professional and enthusiast webmasters focused on how to operate
>   websites. Questions here are about various aspects of owning, running,
>   or administering your own website, such as:

This above was simplified to just:

> Pro Webmasters is a site for asking questions about operating and
>   managing your own website.  Questions here are commonly about, but not
>   limited to:

---

2. Added to the list of on-topic categories is:

   - `Web and email hosting` which was previously just `web hosting`
   - `Website management (e.g., analytics, ads, URLs, etc…)`

Also added there:

> To see other topics that are commonly covered, please view our list of
>   [popular tags](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags). (*Note: 
>   The existence of a tag does not necessarily mean it's on-topic. If
>   you're unsure, you can always ask for confirmation on our
>   [Meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/) site*).

---

3. This was *toned-down* from:

> **Off-topic questions**  There are some types of questions about running websites that don't belong on this site

To:

> Here are some topics that are either considered *off-topic* or better
>   suited for other Stack Exchanges sites:

---

4. `Recommendations for sites and resources` was moved to the top of the list since that's the top reason questions are put on hold. A few minor clarifications were made and typos were corrected.

---

5. `HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding` was changed to: `Coding/programming` since we often get questions about other programming languages too. Some minor clarifications were also made.

---

6. `Web sites out of your control` was changed to: `Websites you don't own or manage` since the former was too vague. Some minor clarifications were also made.

---

7. `Usage of web browsers and other software` was changed to: `Software not related to running your website`

---

8. The description for `Content management systems (CMSs)` was changed from:

> There are specific Stack Exchange sites for several CMSs. Use those
>   sites for Craft CMS, Drupal, Expression Engine, Joomla, Magento,
>   Salesforce, SharePoint, Tridion, or WordPress. Questions about other
>   CMSs may be asked here on Pro Webmasters.

To:

> There are a number of other Stack Exchange sites specific to CMSs that
>   might be better suited for advanced questions, or those unrelated to
>   the on-topic categories listed at the top of this page. In that case,
>   they might be migrated to one of the following sites:  [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/),
>   [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/), [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/), etc… (Please consult the Stack
>   Exchange [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) page for a complete
>   list)

---

9. `Specific to only your site` was too confusing so was changed to: `Only could apply to your site`. The description there was also changed from:

> If the answers to your question could only apply to your site, it is
>   probably not a good fit for Pro Webmasters. For example, we would
>   close questions such as "What am I doing wrong here?" or "Please
>   review my site."

To:

> If the answers to your question could only apply to your site and not
>   others, it's probably not a good fit for Pro Webmasters.  For example,
>   questions such as "What am I doing wrong here?" or "Please review my
>   site" are typically considered *off-topic* since they're unlikely to
>   help future visitors to this site.

---

10. `Topics with a "catch all" question and answer` was removed, and changed from another bullet point into a separate section, since it's really not another "topic" itself. The text there was changed from:

> Many topics are covered by a question with a comprehensive answer.
>   Other questions about the topic are marked as duplicate. Some examples
>   from the list of catch-all questions are:

To:

> Many topics are already covered by a question with a comprehensive
>   answer, so questions asking nearly the same thing are marked as a
>   *duplicate* of those.  Some examples from the list of [catch-all questions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catch-all)
>   are:

---

11. In addition to the above, all the items in **bold** were changed to italics for *emphasis*, so that it doesn't give the impression that we're possibly shouting what's consider off-topic. Sections (horizontal lines) were also added to help organize the page.

---

12. Lastly, a link to this page was added to the home page of the Help Center [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help).

---

** Numbers 1-2 were derived from the answers and comments discussed [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/please-give-us-your-feedback-on-the-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-help-pag/1639#1639) and [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/please-give-us-your-feedback-on-the-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-help-pag/1642#1642).*

*** Numbers 3-12 were derived from my answers [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/please-give-us-your-feedback-on-the-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-help-pag/1637#1637) and [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/there-are-a-lot-of-questions-being-put-on-hold-on-a-daily-basis).*

Comment: Great job, Dan. This is definitely an improvement. Thank you for taking the time to see through to completion.

Comment: You nailed it! This should certainly help. Thanks.

Comment: Good work, those seem to be great improvements.