# The final reckoning: HTML/CSS questions

Tags: discussion

After discussing this topic more then once ([1](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/should-html-css-questions-be-here-if-not-where), [2](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387/html-css-questions-doctype-or-here)) it ultimately boiled down that were to send HTML/CSS coding questions over to StackOverflow. However, very recently they have started sending those very questions over to us ([1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16104/ie-issues-with-my-website-help-me-fix-my-css), [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15981/two-divs-one-fixed-width-the-other-the-rest)). Obviously Webmasters and StackOverflow are not on the same page as to where these belong.

So, which is a better fit? SO or Webmasters?

If it is StackOverflow, how do we communicate this to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on

[What's the deal with migrating CSS questions to Webmasters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96823/whats-the-deal-with-migrating-css-questions-to-webmasters/96825#96825)

I updated the [Pro Webmasters faq](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) to include

> Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it *might* be a better fit on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect **entire websites**.

I don't think it's 100% cut and dried, but it is *imperative* that users understand Pro Webmasters operates at a higher level, namely, the WHOLE WEBSITE level. This does not *rule out* HTML / CSS / JavaScript problems, but it certainly raises the bar substantially.

It's probably easier to explain this as "generally disallowed" than it is to get into specifics that might confuse folks, but despite the risk, I think it would be a worthwhile exercise to post a few links to good **entire website level HTML / CSS / JavaScript questions** here so they can see the difference in scope.

Comment: Examples of HTML questions that operate on the 'whole website level': [1](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/h1-vs-h2-vs-other-for-website-title-logo-and-seo), [2](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/should-my-title-tag-be-the-same-as-my-h1-tag), [3](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16173/whats-the-importance-of-the-title-tag), [4](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)

Answer (score 4):

> So, which is a better fit? SO or
>   Webmasters?

+1 vote for StackOverflow.

> If it is StackOverflow, how do we
>   communicate this to them?

You should have an opportunity to communicate this concern at tomorrow's moderation chat-cast :)

Comment: Hopefully there is more input before then. I'd like to go in there with a good idea of what the community here thinks.

Comment: +1 for SO too. So that's 3 of us.